# Value [] at count of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to double

Tags: php, android, json

I am working on achartengine pie chart to get the value from my database server. I want to show the average marks of the student in each segment. But I am getting error in my logcat stated:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] at count of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to double
```

This is part of my java code:

```
public class c_marks extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GraphicalView mChart;
    private String[] code;
    double value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String COUNT_URL_1 = "http://fypesystem.com/marks_test1.php";
    String COUNT_URL_2 = "http://fypesystem.com/marks_test2.php";
    String COUNT_URL_3 = "http://fypesystem.com/marks_test3.php";
    private static final String TAG_COUNT = "count";
    JSONObject json;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c_marks);

        new Count().execute();
    }

    class Count extends AsyncTask<String,String ,String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COUNT_URL_1);
                value1 = json.getDouble(TAG_COUNT);
                json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COUNT_URL_2);
                value2 = json.getDouble(TAG_COUNT);
                json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COUNT_URL_3);
                value3 = json.getDouble(TAG_COUNT);

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            openChart();
        }
    }
```

The problem may because of my PHP coding because I believe there is problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

marks_test3.php

```
require("config1.php");

$query="SELECT totalmarks, COUNT(*) FROM marks WHERE totalmarks <=30";

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($rows){
    $response["success"]=1;
    $response["message"]=" Available";
    $response["count"]= array();

        array_push($response["count"]);
        echo json_encode($response);

        }else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

Really appreciate if you can tell me the problem.

Comment: For clear understanding, can you share json you have by that php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is a JSON array, but you are trying to reference it as if it were a floating-point number.

You need to either:

### 1. set it as a number when creating the JSON object in PHP and set the value to the number of rows found:

```
$response["count"] = count($rows);
```

In this case, it's probably more correct to use `json.getInt()` than `json.getDouble()`, or

### 2. get `count` as a `JSONArray`, and then check its size:

```
json.getJSONArray("count").length()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to access JSON data 
May be your data is in JSONArray format and you are directly assigning it to float so please use following method

```
try(){
JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(your_data_from_url);

for(int i =0; i<jarray. length();i++){

JSONObject jobject=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
 value1 = jobject.getDouble(TAG_COUNT);
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How about the other two URL?